# How do I remove asterisk from required field in Angular Material

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

When defining a input field as `required` in angular material, it automatically adds a asterisk after the label. I've found a lot of questions asking how to add it, but none how to remove it. It seems that it wasn't default at the time they asked it, but according to this [reference](https://www.google.com/design/spec/components/text-fields.html#text-fields-required-fields) now it is the default behaviour (I'm using the version available on https://github.com/angular/material **).
How do I remove it and get the same behavior as shown [here](https://jsfiddle.net/Styxiak/00eb8z09/) by @Styx.

**By the time I had this problem I thought that I was using the latest release (v. 1.0.5), but I was in fact using the master version, which could have the asterisk feature.

Comment: I'm not familiar the angular material but css would be the fastest solution if it isn't a built in option.

Comment: are you using 'required' or 'ng-required'?

Comment: Both give me the same behavior: 'required' or 'ng-required'.

Comment: I have used angular material but I haven't experienced any such thing. Please got to - https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/input. 
You might be using a custom directive or some kind of angular plugin. Please check for that

Comment: Its wired... Asterisk is going to be a new feature, but it is not merged yet into the project. See this issue: https://github.com/angular/material/pull/6518, status is 'need: merge' Here https://plnkr.co/edit/jjIPtCMEmEwgXinl5IYL?p=preview is code with 1.0.5 version, asterisk is tot there..

Comment: I was pointing to Angular Material github master. So the version wasn't v. 1.0.5. Sorry about the mistake.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Even though it looks like this feature is not yet in 1.0.5, [release notes](https://github.com/angular/material/blob/2515349755c6c829a6580005b04943e52633379d/CHANGELOG.md) ...

I looked through this [commit](https://github.com/angular/material/pull/6518/files#r51372160), and this probably is what we are looking for:

**md-no-asterisk**

```
<input md-maxlength="30" required md-no-asterisk name="description" ng-model="project.description">
```

This is the closed [issue](https://github.com/angular/material/pull/6518) for this feature, status says 'needs: merge'

Comment: Note you can also do `md-no-asterisk="{{hideAsterisks()}}` if you need to.

Answer (score 5):

When using Angular Materials `mat-form-field` you can add the **hideRequiredMarker**

```
<mat-form-field hideRequiredMarker>
  <input required placeholder="type here">
</mat-form-field>
```

Credits to @shivek-parmar
[How do I remove asterisk from required field in Angular Material and add (optional) beside label for optional labels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40217909/how-do-i-remove-asterisk-from-required-field-in-angular-material-and-add-option)