# How do I remove asterisk from required field in Angular Material and add (optional) beside label for optional labels

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am using angular 2 material design for form fields. So with that every required fields appear with asterisk which i don't want.Also, for non-required fields, i want an optional text to be appear in brackets next to the label.

I am using something like below to achieve it but that's not working.

My code-

```
<md-input required md-no-asterisk id="" placeholder="First Name" [(ngModel)]="" ngControl="txtFirstName" #firstName="ngModel"></md-input>
```

When I am removing md-input starting and end tag and just using input tag then the asterisk goes away but some default text called appears as a value of the field.

I want to use required and optional fields as a label.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: I'm not quite sure and I can't test it now, but the asterisk may come from the class applied on the input label. Inspect the element and you should see an `after` property, with your asterisk. Override the class and the asterisk will disappear.

Comment: there is an issue about this on github : 
https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/3681

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, following my comment, I looked on Angular Material's website.

Look :

[image]

as you can see, there's an `after` component, which contains the asterisk. Override this class with your own CSS to get rid of it.

**EDIT :** use the same principle to add your `(optional)` text for non required fields.

Answer (score 39):

For people who are still looking for answer. For Angular material 5 and 6. You can use `[hideRequiredMarker]="hideRequired"`. In you component you can provide its value as hideRequired="true". By this you can show or hide asterisk according to your need. But this directive is a part of `<mat-form-field>` **not of input elements**.

```
<mat-form-field [hideRequiredMarker]="hideRequiredMarker">
  <input matInput placeholder="Simple placeholder" required>
</<mat-form-field>
```

Make sure to check the version of angular and angular material. These should match. Otherwise you can get errors.
Thanks

Comment: This worked for me on Angular Material 15 but I used "true" instead of "hideRequired".
e.g. hideRequiredMarker = "true"

Thanks Shivek

Answer (score 2):

You can also add a provider to your module to set the default option:

```
const matFormFieldDefaultOptions: MatFormFieldDefaultOptions = {
  hideRequiredMarker: true
};

@NgModule({
...
providers: [
    {
      provide: MAT_FORM_FIELD_DEFAULT_OPTIONS,
      useValue: matFormFieldDefaultOptions
    }
  ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

With this you don't need to overwrite css.